# How to use header tags, nav in react-router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have this code

App.tsx

```
import React, { FC, Fragment } from "react";
import Nav from "./Components/Nav/Nav";

const App: FC = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Nav />
  </Fragment>
);

export default App;
```

Nav.tsx

```
const renderUntitled = ({
  match
}: {
  match: faceMatch<{ PageList: string }>;
}) => (
  <Fragment>
     <Logo/>
    <FormSearch params={""} />
    <ButSearch match={match} />
  </Fragment>
);

    const Nav: FC = () => {
      return (<Fragment>
        <nav>
            <Link to="/">Amasia</Link>
            <Link to="/Mens/Hat/ListPage=15&Page=1">Product</Link>
          </nav>
          <Switch>
         <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={({ match }) => (
            <Fragment>
               <Logo/>
              <h1>{"Welcome to Amasia"}</h1>
              <FormSearch params={""} />
              <ButtLogSing />
              <Head match={match} />
            </Fragment>
          )}
        />
       <Route path="/Mens/Hat/:PageList" render={renderUntitled} />
        <Route path="*" render={() => <Redirect to="/" />} />
          </Switch>
          </Fragment>
      );
    };
```

when I click on Amasia, I want this component to open

```
<header>
    <nav> <Nav/> </nav>
    <Logo/>
    <FormSearch params={""} />
    <ButSearch match={match} />
</header>
```

and when you click on Product.

```
<Fragment>
    <header>
        <nav> <Nav/> </nav>
        <Logo/>
        <FormSearch params={""} />
        <ButSearch match={match} />
    </header>
        <Head match={match} />
 </Fragment>
```

I'm new to react.Maybe I did the wrong navigation.the problem is that I don't understand how to use the nav header tags in the react router.To explain to the search engine what is the site navigation and the head of the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as your task is understood, you want to render Header and render different pages under it. This can be done, for example, as follows:

```
const Amasia = () => (
  <div>Amasia</div>
);

const Product = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    Page number: {match.params.page}
  </div>
);

const Header = () => (
  <header>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Amasia</Link>
      <Link to="/Mens/Hat/1">Product</Link>
    </nav>
    <div>Logo</div>
    <div>FormSearch</div>
    <div>ButSearch</div>
  </header>
);

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <main>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Amasia} />
        <Route exact path="/Mens/Hat/:page" component={Product} />
      </Switch>
    </main>
  </>  
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  rootElement,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can render any component in a separate method.

in your nav.tsx file just define a function as follows.

```
function Amasia({ match }) {
  return (
    <header>
       <nav> <Nav/>
       <Logo/>
       <FormSearch params={""} />
       <ButSearch match={match} />
    </header>
  );
}
function Product({ match }) {
  return (
    <Fragment>
       <header>
         <nav> <Nav/>
         <Logo/>
         <FormSearch params={""} />
         <ButSearch match={match} />
       </header>
       <Head match={match} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

and replace the previous route line

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Amasia} /> 
<Route exact path="/Mens/Hat/:PageList" component={Product} />
```

Comment: And in what component will be  `<Route exact path="/" component={Amasia} /> 
<Route exact path="/Mens/Hat/:PageList" component={Product} /> ` ?

Comment: @Uncle you have already added this I just change the component attribute value 
its Nav.tsx file

Comment: You mean I have to write Like this.[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-easley-uex6w) as I understand, if I write inside Router Nav, I will get an eternal cycle.

Comment: I just have given you a basic idea of how you do it in the same file, you can create another file if you want for any component and just call them in the component attribute.